# Image views with playlist offset

Tags: spotify

When using the new [Image view](http://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/preview/views/views-image-image.html) from the Views API to create a player widget, how can I make it play the n-th track in a playlist?

I'm trying to create 5 player widgets that each map to the 1st, 2nd, 3rd, 4th and 5th track of a playlist. The playlist is not accessible to the user and was created with `Playlist.createTemporary()`.

I've looked at `getContextGroupData` but I didn't find any information on how to properly construct a Group object.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit unclear for me exactly what you want to achieve. Do you want five images for the same playlist, but clicking the play button on these five will play different tracks? Or do you want the images to represent the five tracks?

In case of the first scenario: Not possible at the moment. Not sure that we want it to be possible either, since it kind of breaks user expectation if two identical components work differently.

In case of the second scenario: You can get the track objects from the playlist and create an image for each track. However, it will only play that track, and not that track with the playlist as context. Maybe we will expose a way to provide a context in the future.

The getContextGroupData option is for more advanced connections. The new artist view is a good example here. All albums on the artist view are connected, so it will continue playing the next album when the first ends. That's connected by a call to connect() on the list view. Then you get the context group from one of the connected list views and pass that to the image views, to make the image of each album continue playing the next album when the current ends. You can also create the context group yourself (but it doesn't solve your problem here).

Comment: I'm trying to build the second scenario, is there really no way to achieve the desired effect?

Could I instead create 5 temporary playlists and advance to the next track manually by observing the player state changes?

Comment: Hmm, after reading your answer again, I am not sure I understood you correctly.

I'd like to have 5 images that each represent a single track. Then, after the user clicked an image and the track play to the end, it should automatically advance to the next image/track in the list. This seems similar to the behavior of the new artist views, especially when you switch it to grid mode.

Comment: It is a use-case we haven't really thought much of.

Comment: You could try to monitor the player change event and detect when it ends and then move on, but it's a bit fragile. You could also create multiple temporary playlists, with one track in each, and add the playlists to a group (https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/preview/api/api-models-group.html), and then pass the getContextGroupData option to the image view. `Group.create('group').done(function(group) { group.add(playlist1); group.add(playlist2); });` However, I don't know how far we've rolled out clients with this support.